# making a factorial in javascript with recursion beginner

Tags: javascript, recursion, tail-recursion, factorial

```
function nFactorial(n) {
  // return the factorial for n
  // example:
  // the factorial of 3 is 6 (3 * 2 * 1)
  if (n < 0){
    return;
  }

  if (sum === undefined){
    sum = 1;
  }

  sum *= n;
  nFactorial(n - 1);
  return sum;
}

nFactorial(3);
```

I'm doing my first stab at learning recursion in javascript. I'm trying to solve a problem where I'm making a factorial. I error I get right now is

```
ReferenceError: sum is not defined
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm feeling a little lost.

Comment: Where is sum initialized?

Comment: you need a [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) statement together with `sum`. btw, you should call it product.

Comment: initialize sum also read up on how variables and functions are hoisted in javascript. good article: https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

For using a product as return value, you could use [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) of the recursion by using another parameter for the `product` (which replaces the `sum` in the question).

```js
function nFactorial(n, product) {
    product = product || 1;                // default value
    if (n < 0) {                           // exit condition without value
        return;
    }
    if (n === 0) {                         // exit condition with result
        return product;
    }
    return nFactorial(n - 1, n * product); // call recursion at the end of function
}

console.log(nFactorial(3));
```

This approach minimizes the stack length, because the last call does not extend the stack, as opposite of the standard approach of the following recursion without a product parameter.

```js
function nFactorial(n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (n === 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * nFactorial(n - 1);
}

console.log(nFactorial(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you write your code will result always in 0 , here is the correct way for a factorial with recursion, also you need to check if n is a number or the code will trow an error

```js
const factorial =(n)=> {
if(isNaN(n)){
   console.log("enter a number")
   return 0
  }
    if(n === 0) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
    
}
 
console.log(factorial(5));
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple implementation:

```
function factorial(n) {
   if (n === 1 || n === 0) {
     return n;
   }
   return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```